# Is there way to figure out the linear transformation by 3 given images?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have those 3 images:

`T(-1,1,0,1) = (1,-1,2,1)`

`T(1,1,1,0) = (2,3,1,-1)`

`T(-1,5,2,3) = (3,7,0,-3)`.

I need to figure out whether it's a linear transformation,

and if so , find the transformation...... how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Check if the vectors on the left are linearly independent. Solution below

> Well... $u = (-1,1,0,1),\, v = (1,1,1,0),\, w = (-1,5,2,3)$ are linearly dependent since $-3u - 2v + w = 0,$ but $-3T(u) - 2T(v) + T(w) \not = 0,$ so no, $T$ isn't a linear transformation.